# How to sort comments in the "edit-comments.php" table based on a comment meta field?

Tags: wp-admin, comments

#### Goal

Sort comments in the "edit-comments.php" table based on a comment meta field after clicking on the title of a custom made column.

#### Context

For the sake of brevity let's assume that when a comment is posted, a meta field called "hearts" is assigned to it so that all comments have that field which is a positive int from 0 to 10. Of the **bold** steps mentioned below, the first three are given for context and work as intended, the problem is on the 4th step.

**1. Creating the column**

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_columns', 'hearts_add_comments_column' );
function hearts_add_comments_column( $cols ) {
    $cols['hearts'] = 'Hearts';
    return $cols;
}
```

**2. Populating the column**

```
add_action( 'manage_comments_custom_column', 'hearts_column_content', 10, 2 );
function hearts_column_content( $column, $comment_ID ) {
    switch ( $column ) :
        case 'hearts' : {           
            $hearts = get_comment_meta( $comment_ID, 'hearts', true );                  
            echo $hearts;           
            break;
        }
    endswitch;
}
```

**3. Making the column sortable**

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-comments_sortable_columns', 'hearts_make_sortable' );
function hearts_make_sortable( $cols ) {
    $cols['hearts'] = 'by_hearts';
    return $cols;
}
```

**4. Sort based on comment meta**

This is where the problems start, something needs to change in the following code which when tested independently, returns a sorted list of comments as intended:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'hearts_orderby' );
function hearts_orderby( $comments_query ) {
    $orderby = $comments_query->query_vars['orderby'];
 
    if( 'by_hearts' == $orderby ) {
        $comments_query->query(array( 
            'meta_key' => 'hearts',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
        ));         
    }
}
```

Critical Error when clicking on the column's title "Hearts" to sort the column. Redirection to an empty page with the following message:
[image: Critical Error when clicking on the column's title "Hearts" to sort the column.]

**Things tried**

The code below gives no errors, the comments are listed but are not sorted. If i remove the code below entirely, the result is the same. The code is based on the last snippet of [this page](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-make-your-custom-column-sortable--wp-25095).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_comments', 'hearts_orderby' );
function hearts_orderby( $comments_query ) {
    $orderby = $comments_query->query_vars['orderby'];
 
    if( 'by_hearts' == $orderby ) {
        $comments_query->set('meta_key','hearts');
        $comments_query->set('orderby','meta_value_num');   
    }
}
```

#### Questions

1. Is it possible to somehow alter the `hearts_orderby()` function in the 4th step to get the desired outcome?
2. Is it possible to use a different hook in the 4th step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a different hook in the 4th step?

Yes, see [`parse_comment_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/parse_comment_query/) which is also an action hook, but it fires before `pre_get_comments`.

> Is it possible to somehow alter the `hearts_orderby()` function in the
> 4th step to get the desired outcome?

Yes.

But first off, you should know that unlike the `WP_Query` class, `WP_Comment_Query` does not (currently) have a `set()` method, so despite calling `$comments_query->set()` did not cause any error, the `meta_key` and `orderby` args were never actually set.

( `WP_Comment_Query` has a magic [`__call()` method](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__call/), hence calling non-existent methods such as the `set()` would simply return `false` without doing anything else )

Now to make your function works, just set the meta query via direct modification on the `$comments_query->query_vars` array like so:

```php
if( 'by_hearts' == $orderby ) {
    $comments_query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'hearts';
    $comments_query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
}
```

If, however, you want to include comments *without the `hearts` meta*, then you can instead use the `meta_query` arg:

```php
$meta_query = isset( $comments_query->query_vars['meta_query'] ) ?
    (array) $comments_query->query_vars['meta_query'] : array();

$meta_query[] = array(
    'relation'  => 'OR',

    // Include comments having the meta.
    // Match the array key with the $orderby value.
    'by_hearts' => array(
        'key'  => 'hearts',
        'type' => 'NUMERIC',
    ),

    // Include comments without the meta.
    'no_hearts' => array(
        'key'     => 'hearts',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
    ),
);

$comments_query->query_vars['meta_query'] = $meta_query;
```

Comment: Hello again, just tried your first snippet and it worked. I had given up on that implementation because when tested independently, it didn't work: 

`$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query(); $comments_query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'hearts'; $comments_query->query_vars['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num'; 
$comments = $comments_query->comments;`

maybe it is because the query here happens at the first line and the query_vars change afterwards, while in the `pre_get_comments` callback the query hasn't happened yet. Thanks for the detailed answer!